# How to insert a JSON object into SQL Server in Python automatically?

Tags: python, sql-server, etl, pyodbc

I am retrieving some data from an API and inserting it into a local SQL Server database for data analysis purposes.

I would like to create tables and filled it in SQL Server according to the Json object structure I receive. Are there any lib/framework python that can do it automatically?

I am using *pyodbc* to insert the data as below. However, I need to create manually each table in SQL Server and write down field by field on a python script to insert the data.

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers , auth=auth )
parseResponse = json.loads(response.text) 

conn = pyodbc.connect(constant.DW_CONNECTION)
cursor = conn.cursor()

for record in parseResponse:
    print( "Insert Into LeadSource (RequestGuid, [Key], Description, LocationNumber, Inactive, ShowOnline) values " + json.dumps(convert(record)) )
    cursor.execute("Insert Into LeadSource (RequestGuid, [Key], Description, LocationNumber, Inactive, ShowOnline) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", ( record['RequestGuid'], record['Key'], record['Description'], record['LocationNumber'], record['Inactive'], record['ShowOnline'] ) )
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Are you able to use pandas' [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) to pull the JSON into a DataTable and then use [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to upload it to the database?

Comment: I would leave Pandas as a data science tool as opposed to a data migration tool. Also, I would not have a Python script build tables on the fly. Enterprise databases like MSSQL should be planned projects where are all tables are known in advance. Plus, it may be a questionable database design if you need a script to create 50+/100+ tables.

Comment: Well-considered @Parfait. This MSSQL is a temp DW and as I get approval to move to the cloud will use Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gord,

That's what I was looking for. The final code:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers , auth=auth )
parseResponse = json.loads(response.text) 

# Converting the JSON text to Pandas Dataframe
df = pd.read_json(response.text)

# Create an in-memory SQLite database.
engine = sal.create_engine(constant.DW_STR_CONNECTION)
conn = engine.connect()

# Create and insert the entity 'leads' into DW MSSQL
df.to_sql('LeadSource', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index_label='id')
```

DW_STR_CONNECTION should be like:

```
server = hostname\\\SqlInstance

DW_STR_CONNECTION = 'mssql+pyodbc://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + server + '/'+database+'?driver=SQL Server?Trusted_Connection=yes'
```